# Wordpress shortcode security - ob_start() htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, htmlspecialchars, ob-start

I have this piece of code.

```html
function PHP_Include( $atts )
{
 $atts = htmlspecialchars($atts);
 ob_start();  
 
     extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'file' => 'default'
     ), $atts ));
 
 
 include get_theme_root() . '/' . get_template() . '/app/' . $file;
 
 $output = ob_get_contents();   
 ob_end_clean();   
 return $output;
}
```

Someone’s telling me ob_start will make my code more secure, but I don’t understand in which way? Basically, this function will “keep in memory” the code then output the code to execute it, right?

Secondly, when I add `$atts = htmlspecialchars($atts);` the code doesn’t work I have a white page, here again I don’t know why. `$atts is appfile.php`. I use this shortcode `[phpinclude file='appfile.php']`.